# how to elegantly use css sprites in an inline element?

Tags: rollover, sprite, css

I'm aware of [this hack](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/) for inline-block property, but as it really is a *hack* for the poor browser support, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to use CSS sprites without the necessary line-break of block elements.

To illustrate the idea: in the footer of [this website](http://www.alexbrunner.com/moscow) the icons which are inside the footer-text paragraph at the very right bottom of the page should get a nice rollover image. The most elegant technique I know for this is CSS sprites, but that would of course add a line break before the images.

Am I missing something?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Best, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I inline-block hack stuff all over the place, but if you're looking for an alternative, the answer is right on the page you use for an example, in the *other* social icons list nearer to the top of the page.

Just use `display: block` and float the links.

Comment: if for some reason @numbers answer does not suffice, use img elements and css clip property with your sprite.